# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple in Python SVD model

Tags: python, tuples, svd

I am testing a recommender based on SVD model. But I got an error message after running it as below:

Here is my testing code:

```
import sys 
from sys import argv
import csv
import recsys.algorithm
recsys.algorithm.VERBOSE = True
from recsys.algorithm.factorize import SVD
from recsys.datamodel.data import Data

likes = []
with open('/Users/xps13mynotebook/Desktop/w2v/likes.tsv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        username,user_likes = line.strip().split('\t')
        likes.append((username,user_likes))
data = Data()
VALUE = 1.0
for username in likes:
    for user_likes in likes[username]:
        data.add_tuple((VALUE, username, user_likes)) # Tuple format is: <value, row, column>

svd = SVD()
svd.set_data(data)
k = 5 
svd.compute(k=k, min_values=3, pre_normalize=None, mean_center=False, post_normalize=True)

svd.similar('sheila')
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-913000ff4e0e> in <module>()
     10 VALUE = 1.0
     11 for username in likes:
---> 12     for user_likes in likes[username]:
     13         data.add_tuple((VALUE, username, user_likes)) # Tuple format is: <value, row, column>
     14 

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: can't understand your code...its not indented..use likes.username instead of likes[usernsame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're iterating over list of tuples, each value is tuple itself. Your code suggests that's it's a first element of tuple (or index, I'm not quite sure - what's clear is that it's blatantly wrong).

```
for username in likes:
    # username is now tuple from list
    for user_likes in likes[username]:  # list[tuple_stored_in_list] is invalid and causes TypeError
        pass # do something
```

When iterating over list of tuples, use `tuple unpacking` to achieve both element stored in tuple at once:

```
for username, user_likes in likes:
    data.add_tuple((VALUE, username, user_likes)) # Tuple format is: <value, row, column>
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError is saying that you can't access element with a list when you provide it with a tuple, it needs an integer that is the position in the list.

Now why is this happening?

```
likes.append((username,user_likes))
```

and

```
for username in likes:
```

likes is a list where tuples are stored, so your username in like is something like `("mike", 6)`.

Then you are passing that to a list as a position of element. That's why you are getting an error. I don't know exactly what you want your code to do, but right now it's pretty much nonsense